Comments on deleted Staging Ground posts appear undeleted to 10k+ users
When a post on the Staging Ground is deleted, the background coloring suggests that the comments underneath have not been deleted. This is unexpected and curious, but also, in the case of some recent spam posts, that leaves spam comments apparently visible even after the spam post itself is deleted. The deleted page is only visible to users with the privileges to view deleted posts (I think 10k).
Here is one recent example, though the comments here are harmless: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78955454 (deleted, requires 10k)
The background on a deleted question is colored a brownish pink and includes the comments underneath, whereas the colored background on a deleted Staging Ground post does not cover the comments.

(Sorry, somehow managed to post this on MSE originally; now deleted https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402674/comments-on-deleted-staging-ground-posts-appear-undeleted-to-10k-users)

I mean, technically, it is not wrong. Comments aren't deleted, just questions and answers are - comments are just typically included in the red background. It would be interesting whether devs/CMs/designers/people at the company consider this a bug or more of a visual choice though.

Similar thing happens on deleted Discussions but I didn't post a bug cause so few people are affected by it. Should I?
